# Laravel `now('America/Los_Angeles')` is correct on `dd()` but on return result is in UTC

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

For me it's strange, i set `'timezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',`

cleared config & cache.

but now when i `dd(now()) or dd(now('America/Los_Angeles'))` i get

[image]

and when return an array like below, result aren't in desired time zone.

[image]

i want default `now()` return result in desired time zone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, what you see is how it's converted when you ask for JSON.

You can explicitly format it with `->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP T')` or whatever other format or you can change globally how it's converted to string when a Carbon object is returned in a JSON response.

See:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-json
https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1940

Answer (score 0):

The now() method in Laravel returns a Carbon instance, which allows you to set the timezone using the tz() method. However, when you use dd(), it displays the date and time in the timezone you set. But when you return the result, it uses the default timezone of your application, which is set in the config/app.php file.

To make sure that the timezone is correct when you return the result, you can use the tz() method to set the timezone before returning it. For example:

```
$date = now('America/Los_Angeles')->tz('America/Los_Angeles');
return $date;
```

This will set the timezone to America/Los_Angeles before returning the date, so it should display correctly in the browser.